# How can I use dependency injection with dependencies that represent composable behaviors?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, composition

I'm writing an ASP.NET Web Api web service, which needs to make REST calls to other web services. The [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class supports altering its behavior by passing in a [DelegatingMessageHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.aspx) that can implement pre- and post-send functionality.

I'd like to take advantage of HttpClient's composition properties to add various sets of behaviors depending on the web service I'm calling. So, class ServiceA knows what kinds of behaviors it will need to add to HttpClient for the external service it will be calling, and class ServiceB knows what behaviors it will need to add.

I would also like to use dependency injection to supply a ServiceA or ServiceB instance with its required HttpClient instance, so that those dependencies can be easily mocked out for unit testing.

The road I've started down is to create an interface class that represents each set of composed behaviors, so that I can put the interface directly into the constructor of the service class:

```
public interface IFooBarHttpClient
{
    HttpResponseMessage SendAsync( HttpRequestMessage ); // etc
}
public class ServiceA
{
    public ServiceA( IFooBarHttpClient httpclient ) {}
}
```

And then implement that interface with a class which inherits from HttpClient and adds in the DelegatingMessageHandlers it needs when calling the base class constructor.

I see two problems with this approach:

1. Any time I need another combination of behaviors, I'll need to create a new interface and implementation class for that specific combination. This really becomes an issue with naming each new interface/implementation.
2. I feel like this is abusing the type system. The interfaces themselves are all exactly the same, except for the name. The interfaces are really just configuration tags for the IoC container.

Ideally, I'd like something like this (Foo and Bar being message handlers, ie composable behaviors):

```
public class ServiceA
{
    public ServiceA( IHttpClient< Foo, Bar > httpclient ) {}
}
```

Is there a reasonable way to use dependency injection for classes composing behaviors in this way? Or should I be thinking in a different direction?

Comment: See these articles [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)